# Android Studio can't request permission for writing all files in external storage

Tags: java, android, permissions

I added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />` into my manifest. And I receive a window which allows me to get permission for writing media files. But I need to write .txt files in the external storage and I can get it only by my hands. How can I cause spawning the window for getting full permission automatically?

Comment: Are you requesting permission like ```ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), code)``` this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's that I was looking for. Just add it to MainActivity onCreate():

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
            // If you don't have access, launch a new activity to show the user the system's dialog
            // to allow access to the external storage
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", this.getPackageName(), null);
            intent.setData(uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).